How to skip first line of a csv while uploading it using hotfolder in hybris?
I only know about a workaround that too I have not tried but only this was available during my research  - "failOnError" and purposefully give the first line wrong.
But I want to know how exactly it would be done even if the first line is right.

In file hot-folder-spring.xml you have declaration of a bean called batchTransformerTask. One of its properties is called linesToSkip.
Out of the box its set to 0, but you can set it to any number you want, and it will be applied to all incoming feeds.

in your converter bean add
<property name="enableEscaping" value="1"/>

for example:
<bean id="batchManufacturerConverter" parent="abstractDefaultImpexConverter">
        <property name="header">
            <value>#{defaultImpexManufacturerHeader}
                INSERT_UPDATE Manufacturer; code[unique = true]; name; about; email; $productCV
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="impexRow">
            <value>;{+0};{1};{2};{3}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="type" value="Manufacturer"/>
        <property name="enableEscaping" value="1"/>
    </bean>

